# filming iridescent liquid or effect

Tags: effects

I am going to shoot a music video where i want to have a iridescent effect. 
I could shoot a liquid with iridescent effect and then use it as background for the scene using green screen.
But... how to do that??
Any ideas on lighting or somebody that have done this before?
Thank you.
Luca

[image]

[image]

Comment: Please clarify:  Do you want to know how to light a green screen and the people in front of it?  Or do you want to know how to create those iridescent effects?

Comment: i'd like to know how to create those iridescent effects. i'd like to shoot real liquid!

Comment: Those do look really cool. Sorry but I don't know how they're shot! You can probably Google "how to shoot iridescent effect", and you will find some good advice.

Comment: The second image looks like paint, which should be easier to shoot than clear or translucent liquids. I don't remember a whole lot about shooting liquids, but I do remember that clear liquids need to be back lit in order to be seen.

Comment: yeah! i'll make some experiments :)

Comment: you could also try looking at stock libraries, they have a ton of that stuff and you won't get paint all over your camera ;)

Comment: watch at this! https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=eEDunSMssrw

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you are asking is not quite clear, but if you want to have the colored liquids in front of your people, just add the video on top of the main video, and just change the opacity of the colored liquids. If you want the iridescent liquids behind your people, shoot the main video in front of a green screen with fairly good lighting, then add the colored liquid in after, utilizing the green screen.

Hope this helps!